# c# exit NetworkStream.read()

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, stream

I have created a TCP listener to receive data from a port. And I created a NetworkStream to read the coming data.

```
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(TCPSocket);
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[128];
int i;
while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
{
     string msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
     Console.WriteLine("received: {0}", msg);
}
```

What I want to do is, if there is no data coming for 10 minutes, I want to close the stream. How can I do this? I have tried to use timer with creating a thread to call stream.close() after sometime, but nothing worked before it receive any data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried stream.ReadTimeOut = 600000;

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need, can I mark your answer as the solution? I know this is easy but I just missed it and you really helped me out! @active92

Comment: sure.great to be able to help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
stream.ReadTimeOut = 600000;
```

it is in milliseconds.